# Error mounting in fstab Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, filesystems, mount

I'm working on a bash class project which needs me to create 2 partitions in Ubuntu and make them be automatically mounted each time the systems boots with fstab.

I got the following file which creates (I think correctly) the 2 partitions needed and adds them to the fstab file.

```
#!/bin/bash

#SVN Partition
(echo n; echo p; echo ; echo ; echo +20G; echo w;) | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

#WEB Partition
(echo n; echo p; echo ; echo ; echo +5G; echo w;) | sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

sudo su -c "echo '/dev/sdb1        /svn  ext4    rw,user,auto,utf8      0       0' >> /etc/fstab"
sudo su -c "echo '/dev/sdb2        /web  ext4    rw,user,auto,exec,utf8 0       0' >> /etc/fstab"
```

When I reboot the system an error appears telling me the automatic mounting for /web and /svn failed.

Does anyone have a clue on what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is better asked @ http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @AlexK. or http://superuser.com

Comment: Did you try to run this command manually in terminal?

Comment: Please read the boot.log file and syslog file in /var/log folder

Comment: Do you have /svn and /web folders?

Comment: The /svn and /web folders are created, yes.

Comment: format the filesystems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't formatted the filesystems...

Execute these before reboot.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: Meh, that was really dumb of me to forget that. Thanks for your help! Would've been stuck here a few more hours if it wasn't for you.. ._.